# Задание поля класса

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Хочу сделать метод который принимал бы два значения: название поля и экземпляр класса, и задавал бы по ключу названия этот экземпляр.
То-есть примерно сделующее:

```
class GameObject{
  addComponent(name, component){
      this.name = component;
    }
  }
```

По-сути некий аналог addComponent в unity.
Как сделать так, чтобы интерпретатор воспринимал name не как поле, которое нужно задать, а как переменную (надеюсь, понятно объяснила:) )

Comment: Это называется "скобочная нотация" и не является чем-то новым. Значение любого объекта можно достать как через скобки, так и через точку... в смысле, `this.name` == `this["name"]` то же самое, просто точка короче. Только, точку используют для обычных строк, а в скобки можно добавить и переменные, вычисляемые выражения и т.п.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```
class GameObject {
  addComponent(name, component) {
      this[name] = component;
  }
}
```